# Laravel dompdf taking too much time to generate and download a pdf

Tags: pdf-generation, laravel-6, reportgenerator, laravel-dompdf

I'm recently working on report generation for simple 2 records from database. For generating this report i'm using Laravel dompdf package, but it's taking too long time to download which is not expected. Code I used is below:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('dashboard.sales-report', compact('sales'));
$pdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$sales_report_file_name = "daily_sales_".date('Y-m-d').".pdf";
return $pdf->download($sales_report_file_name);
```

and using css inside our view page. But only two records taking more than 2 minutes. Could anyone please help me on it? Thanks in advance.

Blade file code:

```
@extends('layouts.invoice_master')
@section('content')
@php
  $total_discount = 0;
  $total_advance = 0;
  $total_net_sum = 0;
  $total = 0;
@endphp
  <!-- START CONTAINER FLUID -->
    <div class=" container-fluid   container-fixed-lg">
      <!-- START card -->
      <div class="card card-default m-t-20">
        <div class="card-body">
          <!-- Define header and footer blocks before your content -->
          <header>
              <p>{{ $report_for }} </p>
              <p>{{ $report_for_date }}</p>
              <p>{{ $report_for_month }}</p> 
          </header>                          
          <div class="invoice padding-50 sm-padding-10" style="padding-left:unset !important;">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3" style="padding-left:5px !important;">
                <img style="width: 200px;margin-bottom: 20px" alt="" class="invoice-logo" src="{{ asset('uploads/company/'.$company_details->id.'/receipt_logo/'.$company_details->receipt_logo)}}">                
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-8">                
                <address class="m-t-10">
                  @if($out_let)
                    {{ $out_let[0]->name }}
                  <br>{{ $out_let[0]->location }}
                  <br>{{ $out_let[0]->address }}
                  <br>{{ $out_let[0]->city }} , {{ $out_let[0]->zip }}
                  <br>Contact: {{ $out_let[0]->phone }}
                  <br>
                  @endif
                </address>
              </div>                 
            </div>  
            <div class="clearfix"></div>            
            <div class="table-responsive table-invoice">
              <table class="table m-t-25">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Date</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Invoice</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Customer</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Total</th>  
                    <th class="text-center">Discount</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Net.Sum</th>  
                    <th class="text-center">Advance</th> 
                    <th class="text-center">Remain</th>  
                    <th class="text-center">Currency</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  @if( $sales )
                    @foreach( $sales as $sale )
                      <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">
                          {{ $sale->created_at }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                          <p class="text-black">
                            @if(isset($sale->invoice_prefix_id))
                            {{ 
                              App\InvoicePrefix::find($sale->invoice_prefix_id)->name    
                            }}-{{ $sale->invoice_no 
                             }}                                                    
                            @else
                            {{ $sale->invoice_no }}
                            @endif
                          </p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                          @if(isset($sale->customer_id))
                            {{ App\Customer::find($sale->customer_id)->first_name }} 
                            {{ App\Customer::find($sale->customer_id)->last_name }}
                            ( {{ App\Customer::find($sale->customer_id)->customer_no}} )
                          @else
                            Guest
                          @endif
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                          @php
                            $total = $sale->sub_total + $sale->vat_amount;
                            echo  number_format($total);
                          @endphp
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                          @php
                            $total_discount = number_format($total_discount + ($sale->discount_amount +  $sale->coupon_discount_amount));
                            echo  number_format($sale->discount_amount +  $sale->coupon_discount_amount);
                          @endphp
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                          @php 
                            echo number_format($sale->net_amount);                    
                          @endphp
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                          @if(isset($sale->id))                          
                           @php
                              $advance = App\SalePaid::where('sale_id', $sale->id)->sum('paid_amount');                              
                              if($advance <= $sale->net_amount){
                                echo number_format($advance); 
                              }else{
                                echo number_format($sale->net_amount); 
                                $advance = $sale->net_amount;
                              }
                              $total_advance = $total_advance + $advance;
                              
                            @endphp                                                    
                          @endif
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                          @php 
                            echo number_format(max(($sale->net_amount - App\SalePaid::where('sale_id', $sale->id)->sum('paid_amount')), 0)); 
                            $total_net_sum = $total_net_sum + $sale->net_amount;                   
                          @endphp
                        </td>                        
                        <td class="text-center">
                          @if(isset($sale->company_currency_id))
                            {{ 
                              App\Currency::find(App\CompanyCurrency::find($sale->company_currency_id)->currency_id)->code                              
                            }} 
                          @else
                            N/A
                          @endif
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    @endforeach
                  @endif
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div> 
            <br>                          
            <div class="panel-heading title-color">
              <table class="table table-hover table-heading" id="tableWithSearch">
                  <tbody class="table-body">
                      <tr>
                          <td class="v-align-middle">
                            <h5 class="font-montserrat all-caps small hint-text semi-bold">Discount: BDT 
                            @php
                              echo number_format($total_discount);
                            @endphp</h5>
                          </td>                          
                          <td class="v-align-middle">
                            <h5 class="font-montserrat all-caps small hint-text semi-bold">Advance: BDT  
                            @php 
                                echo number_format($total_advance); 
                            @endphp
                            </h5>
                          </td>
                          <td class="v-align-middle">
                             <h5 class="font-montserrat all-caps small hint-text semi-bold">Remain Sum: BDT 
                             @php 
                                echo number_format(max(($total_net_sum - $total_advance), 0));
                             @endphp
                             </h5>
                          </td>
                          <td class="v-align-middle">
                            <h5 class="font-montserrat all-caps small hint-text bold">Net. Sum: BDT 
                              @php 
                                echo number_format($total_net_sum); 
                              @endphp
                            </h5>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
            </div><br/>          
            <div class="stamp-signature"> 
              <div class="authority-signature">
                Printed By: {{ Auth::user()->userDetail ? Auth::user()->userDetail->first_name : '' }} {{ Auth::user()->userDetail ? Auth::user()->userDetail->last_name : '.......................' }} 
              </div>              
              <div class="customer-signature">
                Authorized By: .......................
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div> 
                <span class="bold hint-text">Notes: </span>
                <span class="small hint-text">This report generated on Date: {{ $report_generated_on }}. Please issue company stamp and sign in above section.
              </span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="footer-border" style="width: 100% !important;"></div>
            <footer> 
              <div class="footer-logo">
                 <img style="width: 80px; height: 22px;" alt="" class="invoice-logo" src="{{ asset('uploads/company/'.$company_details->id.'/receipt_logo/50x50/'.$company_details->receipt_logo)}}">
              </div>
              @if($out_let)
                <div class="footer-info-text">
                  | <span class="m-l-70 text-black sm-pull-right"> {{ $out_let[0]->name }} </span>
                  | <span class="m-l-70 text-black sm-pull-right"> 
                      {{ $out_let[0]->phone }}</span> <br/><br/>
                      <span class="m-l-70 text-black sm-pull-right"> Software By: {{ env('APP_URL')}}</span><br/>
                </div>
              @endif               
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END card -->
    </div>
  <!-- END CONTAINER FLUID -->
@endsection
```

Here comes controller function:

```
/**
 * Generate daily sales report for logged user's Outlet
 *
 * @return Pdf generated report
 */
protected function dailyReport(){        
    $company_details = $this->getCompanyDetails();        
    $report_for = "Daily Sales Report";
    $report_for_date = "Date: ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $report_for_month = "";    
    $from_date = $today_date = date('Y-m-d');
    $report_generated_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $out_let = OutLet::where('id',$_COOKIE['out_let_id'])->get();
    $sales = Sale::whereDate('sale_date',date('Y-m-d'))->where('out_let_id',$_COOKIE['out_let_id'])->get();    

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('dashboard.sales-report', compact('out_let','sales', 'report_for','report_for_date','from_date','today_date','report_for_month','report_generated_on','company_details'));


    // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
    $pdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
    // download PDF file with download method
    $sales_report_file_name = "daily_sales_".date('Y-m-d').".pdf";
    return $pdf->download($sales_report_file_name);
}
```

Here comes new blade file code where no DB query:

```
@extends('layouts.invoice_master')
@section('content')
@php
  $total_discount = 0;
  $total_advance = 0;
  $total_net_sum = 0;
  $total = 0;
@endphp
  <!-- START CONTAINER FLUID -->
    <div class=" container-fluid   container-fixed-lg">
      <!-- START card -->
      <div class="card card-default m-t-20">
        <div class="card-body">
          <!-- Define header and footer blocks before your content -->
          <header>
              <p>{{ $report_for }} </p>
              <p>{{ $report_for_date }}</p>
              <p>{{ $report_for_month }}</p> 
          </header>                          
          <div class="invoice padding-50 sm-padding-10" style="padding-left:unset !important;">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3" style="padding-left:5px !important;">
                <img style="width: 200px;margin-bottom: 20px" alt="" class="invoice-logo" src="{{ asset('uploads/company/'.$company_details->id.'/receipt_logo/'.$company_details->receipt_logo)}}">            
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-8">                
                <address class="m-t-10">
                  @if($out_let)
                    {{ $out_let[0]->name }}
                  <br>{{ $out_let[0]->location }}
                  <br>{{ $out_let[0]->address }}
                  <br>{{ $out_let[0]->city }} , {{ $out_let[0]->zip }}
                  <br>Contact: {{ $out_let[0]->phone }}
                  <br>
                  @endif
                </address>
              </div>                 
            </div>  
            <div class="clearfix"></div>            
            <div class="table-responsive table-invoice">
              <table class="table m-t-25">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Date</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Invoice</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Customer</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Total</th>  
                    <th class="text-center">Discount</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Net.Sum</th>  
                    <th class="text-center">Advance</th> 
                    <th class="text-center">Remain</th>  
                    <th class="text-center">Currency</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  @if( $sales )
                    @foreach( $sales as $sale )
                      <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">
                          {{ $sale->created_at }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                          <p class="text-black">
                            @if(isset($sale->invoice_prefix_id))
                              Saj-{{ $sale->invoice_no 
                             }}                                                    
                            @else
                            {{ $sale->invoice_no }}
                            @endif
                          </p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                          @if(isset($sale->customer_id))
                            abu taher
                          @else
                            Guest
                          @endif
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                          @php
                            $total = $sale->sub_total + $sale->vat_amount;
                            echo  number_format($total);
                          @endphp
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                          @php
                            $total_discount = number_format($total_discount + ($sale->discount_amount +  $sale->coupon_discount_amount));
                            echo  number_format($sale->discount_amount +  $sale->coupon_discount_amount);
                          @endphp
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                          @php 
                            echo number_format($sale->net_amount);                    
                          @endphp
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                          @if(isset($sale->id))                          
                           @php
                              $advance = "250";                            
                              if($advance <= $sale->net_amount){
                                echo number_format($advance); 
                              }else{
                                echo number_format($sale->net_amount); 
                                $advance = $sale->net_amount;
                              }
                              $total_advance = $total_advance + $advance;
                              
                            @endphp                                                    
                          @endif
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                          @php 
                            echo number_format(max(($sale->net_amount - 250), 0)); 
                            $total_net_sum = $total_net_sum + $sale->net_amount;                   
                          @endphp
                        </td>                        
                        <td class="text-center">
                          @if(isset($sale->company_currency_id))
                            BDT
                          @else
                            N/A
                          @endif
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    @endforeach
                  @endif
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div> 
            <br>                          
            <div class="panel-heading title-color">
              <table class="table table-hover table-heading" id="tableWithSearch">
                  <tbody class="table-body">
                      <tr>
                          <td class="v-align-middle">
                            <h5 class="font-montserrat all-caps small hint-text semi-bold">Discount: BDT 
                            @php
                              echo number_format($total_discount);
                            @endphp</h5>
                          </td>                          
                          <td class="v-align-middle">
                            <h5 class="font-montserrat all-caps small hint-text semi-bold">Advance: BDT  
                            @php 
                                echo number_format($total_advance); 
                            @endphp
                            </h5>
                          </td>
                          <td class="v-align-middle">
                             <h5 class="font-montserrat all-caps small hint-text semi-bold">Remain Sum: BDT 
                             @php 
                                echo number_format(max(($total_net_sum - $total_advance), 0));
                             @endphp
                             </h5>
                          </td>
                          <td class="v-align-middle">
                            <h5 class="font-montserrat all-caps small hint-text bold">Net. Sum: BDT 
                              @php 
                                echo number_format($total_net_sum); 
                              @endphp
                            </h5>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
            </div><br/>          
            <div class="stamp-signature"> 
              <div class="authority-signature">
                Printed By: ABU TAHER 
                ....................... 
              </div>              
              <div class="customer-signature">
                Authorized By: .......................
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div> 
                <span class="bold hint-text">Notes: </span>
                <span class="small hint-text">This report generated on Date: {{ $report_generated_on }}. Please issue company stamp and sign in above section.
              </span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="footer-border" style="width: 100% !important;"></div>
            <footer> 
              <div class="footer-logo">
                 <img style="width: 80px; height: 22px;" alt="" class="invoice-logo" src="{{ asset('uploads/company/'.$company_details->id.'/receipt_logo/50x50/'.$company_details->receipt_logo)}}">
              </div>
              @if($out_let)
                <div class="footer-info-text">
                  | <span class="m-l-70 text-black sm-pull-right"> {{ $out_let[0]->name }} </span>
                  | <span class="m-l-70 text-black sm-pull-right"> 
                      {{ $out_let[0]->phone }}</span> <br/><br/>
                      <span class="m-l-70 text-black sm-pull-right"> Software By: {{ env('APP_URL')}}</span><br/>
                </div>
              @endif               
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END card -->
    </div>
  <!-- END CONTAINER FLUID -->
@endsection
```

Comment: This is hard to say without seeing `sales-report.blade.php`; you might be doing something in there (like iterating those 2 records and calling some DB queries, etc.). There will always be some overhead associated with using both Laravel and DomPDF, but you haven't shared enough code for us to help in any meaningful way aside from guessing.

Comment: I edited my post where comes blade file code.

Comment: As I suspected! You have _a lot_ of DB calls in your `.blade.php` file, like `InvoicePrefix::find(...)`, `Customer::find(...)` (x3), `SalePaid::find(...)` (x2), `Currency::find(...)` and `CompanyCurrency::find(...)`. For each row of `$sales`, that is 8 additional queries. If you have relationships, you would do `$sales = Sale::with(['invoicePrefix', 'customer', 'salePaid', 'currency.companyCurrency'])`, then reference `$sale->invoicePrefix`, `$sale->customer`, `$sale->salePaid`, `$sale->currency->companyCurrency`, etc., and skip all the additional queries.

Comment: For more information, check the documentation on Eager Loading: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading. The TL;DR is that you should never query data in a `.blade.php` file; that should be done in the Controller, and doubly so if you're doing these additional queries in a loop, like `@foreach($sales as $sale)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I 've followed exactly what you said. But no luck, still same problem I can see. Is there any other issues do you think?

Comment: If you have followed _exactly_ what I suggested, you wouldn't be facing the same problem. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74267426/edit) and include your new code. I don't see anything else wrong with your question (except you didn't show how you're defining `$sales` before calling `compact('sales')`, so there _might_ be something there). But yeah. If you don't update your question with the new code, I won't be able to help further.

Answer (score 7):

Finally I solved the issue myself. The problem was in img tag image loading path. Previously using below img tag where path was wrong according to pdf generation and due to that system was unable to load the image, so it was taking too much time:
Previous img tag:

```
<img style="width: 80px; height: 22px;" alt="" class="invoice-logo" src="{{ asset('uploads/company/'.$company_details->id.'/receipt_logo/50x50/'.$company_details->receipt_logo)}}">
```

New img tag where image path is different than upper one, and here everything working fine including time.

```
<img style="width: 80px; height: 22px;" alt="" class="invoice-logo" src="{{ public_path().'/uploads/company/'.$company_details->id.'/receipt_logo/50x50/'.$company_details->receipt_logo }}">
```

Comment: On my local env, even though the path was correct using public_path() i got the same issue. So keep that in mind.